# UML Activity Diagram: Get the multiplicity of a class's 0..* attribute

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

How does one go about getting the number of elements in a class's attribute that has 0..* multiplicity?

I can only think of either using an << iterate>> construct to do so but that seems silly or a counter whenever something is added.  This seems inelegant if not inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to refer to the cardinality of an attribute in an activity diagram, you can use the `size()` function. Example:

[image: diamond]

If your activity diagram is meant to be read by humans, not by machines, you can also just simply write "number of elements in object.attr".

If you want to access the cardinality in order to create a loop, you might prefer the expansion region. An iterate construct in activity diagrams can be achieved by using an expansion region with mode = iterative. Suppose class `Order` has attribute `orderline` of type `OrderLine[1..*]`. The following diagram shows how to iterate over all orderlines.

[image: activity-diagram]

See section 16.12 of the UML 2.5.1 specification for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  For Cameo users: https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD190/Built-in+operations

Comment: there is one small mistake in this answer: the arrow `->` notation is only for collections. `object` is not a collection, therefore it should be `object.attr->size()`.

Comment: Another problem is the expansion region. It needs to have an object flow with a collection arriving at the expansion node. Therefore, the order input parameter should be connected to it directly and the transformation  `order.orderline` should be used on the object flow. The text `for each order.orderline` has no meaning here. The expansion region already means, that it will be executed for each of the elements of the incoming collection.

Answer (score 1):

A multiplicity of `0..*` means that for a given instance `a` of `A` there is a collection of associated instances of `B` that has has at minimum 0 and at maximum *  (i.e. no upper limit) elements:

[image]

The same is true for an attribute `b:B [0..*]` that a class `A` could have.

The number of elements in the collection is called cardinality.  In a constraint, you can refer to the cardinality with

```
self.b->size()
```

There is also a convenient way to check if the collection is empty or not:

```
self.b->isEmpty()
self.b->notEmpty()
```

Comment: What is the diagrammatic means of implementing t his?

Comment: @JordanMcBain what do you try to achieve? Isn’t it for setting constraints?

Comment: It sounds like you know more about the subject than I do.  I would like to put the "isEmpty()" function on my diagram somehow?

Comment: Between curly braces directly in the diagram or in a note:  { self->b->isEmpty() } - more visual explanations here: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/how-to-model-constraints-in-uml/

Comment: @AxelScheithauer indeed. And moreover, it's not the first time you remind me.  Corrected.